# Getting peak private bytes value for process in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, performancecounter

ProcessExplorer somehow obtain this value and show it on Performance tab for each process... How to get it using Win32 API?

**Solution:**
In `Peak Private Bytes' field, Process Explorer actually shows "Process\...\Page File Bytes Peak" performance counter. This value could be easily retrieved with PSAPI function GetProcessMemoryInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetProcessMemoryInfo` gets you this:

> [**PrivateUsage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>
> The current amount of memory that cannot be shared with other
>   processes, in bytes. Private bytes include memory that is committed
>   and marked MEM_PRIVATE, data that is not mapped, and executable pages
>   that have been written to.

Comment: I need to know peak memory consumption not the current value

Comment: My understanding is that where it says `Peak Private Bytes', Process Explorer actually shows Process\\<instance>\\Page File Bytes Peak value - those perfectly match across running processes for me.

Answer (score 1):

The info on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ab076e67-7e56-4545-a680-cccf294b9e2c) may be out of date, but it does suggest that this data is extracted via the kernel, and is not publicly available via Win32.